# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using an .ascx user control where i populating employee data along with employee picture.
while on clicking employee picture i want to display a dialog where i want to have one text field and a text box for input from user. Click event is firing fine but with dialog it gives me the error of "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'". Could please anyone help me to populate a dialog with a text field and text box. I am really new to the JQUERY and struggling to get it work.

In the following code snippet i have added a dialog code from one of the example i found online.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OpenAccessDataProvider,a4a794260c0b4440b466f75d11146db8.ascx.cs" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.SfCtrlPresentation.OpenAccessDataProvider_a4a794260c0b4440b466f75d11146db8" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.BrowseAndEdit" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ContentUI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Comments" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<telerik:RadListView ID="dynamicContentListView" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="sfitemsList sfitemsListTitleDateTmb">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
      <li class="sfitem sfClearfix">
            <h2 class="sfitemTitle">
                <sf:DetailsViewHyperLink ID="DetailsViewHyperLink" TextDataField="Title" runat="server" />
            </h2>
           <sf:AssetsField ID="AssetsField1" runat="server" DataFieldName="Picture" />
           <sf:SitefinityLabel ID="SitefinityLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Designation")%>'  WrapperTagName="div" HideIfNoText="true" CssClass="sfitemShortTxt" />           
          <sf:SitefinityLabel ID="SitefinityLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName")%>' WrapperTagName="div" HideIfNoText="true" CssClass="sfitemShortTxt" />
          <sf:AssetsField ID="AssetsField2" runat="server" DataFieldName="Documents"/>
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>

<sf:Pager id="pager" runat="server"></sf:Pager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sfClearfix .sfimageWrp img").click(function () {

//            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

                $('#opener').click(function () {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                    return false;
                });
//            });

            //alert("HEY THERE " + $(this).attr("src")); 
        });
    });
</script>

Regards.
```

Comment: it seems like jquery ui.js is not being loaded also keep in mind you have to include jquery.js before including any other library

Comment: Thanks for the advise 3nigma. I know jquery.js is not included in my code but as i mentioned i am working with a user control (.ascx file) where i dont know if i am allowed to add jquery.js script as we add any script in the header of .aspx pages while in user controls i dont have any header. any advise for that? i tried adding script directly and I am still ending up with same error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'"

Comment: It's some sort of an annoying conflict with the Telerik libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working guys. Just added a div that is for dialog and than from picture click just called the div. Also, added a JQuery.noConflict(); to prevent any conflicts between Sitefinity and JQuery libraries. Following is the code snippet

```
<div class="dialogTest"> <br />
<br />
Please enter your email address: <input type="text" name="emailAddress" style="width:300px;" /><br /><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="False" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".sfClearfix .sfimageWrp img").click(function () {
        $j(".dialogTest").addClass("open");
        //return $j(this).attr("src");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Had some conflict between telerik and jquery and so the jquery ui dialog would throw an error. $j = jQuery.noConflict(); worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, jquery files are not loaded properly. So what I did are:
1) Opened the page at Chrome
2) Selected the Developer tools from the menu or Ctrl+Shift+I
3) Clicked on Network to see all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. problem was I had loaded 2 Jquery files. jquery-1.8.3.js and jquery-1.4.1.js . so there was a conflict. after removing jquery-1.4.1.js file . it worked smoothly.